# Mysql query efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

We have a table called product with productID as primary key. Then we have table called productProcess where store the productID and processID. So now we want to search all productID which does not have an instance in the productProcess table. Currently we run two query first all the product and second is the productID from productProcess and those does not exist is selected. Is there any other mechanism for this?

Comment: Am having this table, am having that table, but where's the query which has to be optimized?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Comment: I have first select productId from tblProduct. Then I tried select distinct productID from tblProductProcess. Then I compare both and chose those productID does not exist in the second query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*      // this will get all columns from product table.
FROM    product a
        LEFT JOIN productProcess b
            ON a.productID = b.productID
WHERE   b.productID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b410/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Another tip to make if faster is to set `productID` of table `productProcess` a foreign key.

Comment: yes productID is the foreign key but I dont understand why must we put b.productID IS NULL ?

Comment: oh i see, Remember that we are are using `LEFT JOIN` and it returns all records from the left hand side table. The records that has no matching ID on the second table will have a value of null on the other columns. For demonstration: [>>CLICK_HERE<<](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b410/3)

Comment: ok I am getting it clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming product.productID *cannot be NULL*:

```
SELECT product.productID 
FROM product
LEFT JOIN productProcess
ON productProcess.productID = product.productID
WHERE productProcess.productID IS NULL
```

Another option is `WHERE NOT EXIST`:

```
SELECT product.productID
FROM product
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT productID FROM productProcess
  WHERE productProcess.productID = product.productId
)
```

Comment: which is faster in generating results?

Comment: Test it, that will tell you. Both work about equal here, but it tends to drift a bit in different mysql server versions.

Comment: ok I will test it but I think the first query you have to swap this ON productProcess.productID = product.productID

Comment: Erm, swapping? Care to elaborate? At the moment I see nothing wrong with the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a left join.
If you can use a left join, the result will be all the products that have relation into products and ProductsProcess.

```
SELECT  p.* 
FROM    (product p LEFT JOIN productProcess pp ON a.productID = b.productID)
WHERE   pp.productID IS NULL
```